# What are some time saving functions and expressions do you have for SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

What time saving functions have you written or found for SSRS?

My main one is a safedivide function that I use wherever I think there could be a chance of a divide by zero error happening:

```
Function SafeDivide(value1 As Decimal, value2 As Decimal) As Decimal

        If (value1 <> 0.0 And value2 <> 0.0) Then
            Return value1 / value2
        Else
            Return 0
        End If

End Function
```

Are there any others that you use frequently and can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's simpler like this.

```
Function SafeDivide(value1 As Decimal, value2 As Decimal) As Decimal
        If value2 = 0 return 0
        Return value1 / value2
End Function
```

We have also have an **in house utility** which we wrote that updates all code in a project's reports from a single code file.

My point is that you can use any .net code in SSRS, so you should investigate common libraries of useful code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this library? I don't believe my workplace is using this, but should be. Do you have a link to any resources regarding it?